# ipa uploaded successfully but not showing after upload completes xcode 8

Tags: ios, iphone, build, upload, app-store-connect

While my build is uploading, it shows in iTunes Connect, but when uploading gets completed successfully the build no longer shows on iTunes Connect, it get vanished from there.

I tried with both XCode 8 and application loader. I added all required keys in info.plist for usage descriptions.

[image: Build status in iTunes connect.]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check the message from Apple. Recently I also faced same issue. The reason was pretty simple, I missed description keys in info.plist. **These keys are mandatory** in **Xcode 8 + iOS 10 SDK**

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   **NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription** key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   **NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription** key with a string value
>   explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Additionally, I was also forced to include "Camera usage description key". I uploaded again with new bundle number, and build reflected in iTunes connect.

Answer (score 0):

This is overcrowded question so this problem is multiple type of process you can try.

This processing step taking around 15 to 20 minutes as it usually does, now applications stay in processing for 24 hours or more at a time.

**Try 1 - Upload new binary:**

upload a new binary of the same application with an incremented build number.

**Try 2 - Avoid using Bitcode**

[image]
If you've enabled Bitcode in your application,This can be done by going to Setup: Project>Build Settings>All>Build Options and setting "Enable Bitcode" to NO after this you should recompile the app, archive and upload it again using iTunes Connect.

**Try 3. Use Application Loader**

[image]

use the Application Loader utility to upload a new build of your app. After the upload process finishes, your app should also get out of the "Processing" status.

**Try 4. Use the latest Xcode.**

iTunes Connect "Processing" issue and managed to solve it, using Latest Xcode to build and upload your app might just be the winning solution for your problems.

**Try 5. Go to Contact**

"Resources & Help" in iTunes Connect. Select "Contact Us".

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities in this:
1. You are using outdated Xcode to upload. Try the latest one, because apple support stop working for old xcodes after launch of new xcode version.

2. Your permissions in plist are not available, like you may be using camera feature, photos feature, location feature but permissions are not given in plist so kindly add keys for the permissions in plist..

The best way to figure out about the issue is to check the email ID that is registered with Apple developer account, you must have received email from Apple about the missing component in code. That makes the build of application invalid, so check email first to figure out what exactly the main issue is. It clearly states the next steps. Most of the time above 2 issues are found when build is not appearing in iTunes.